# php mcrypt equivalent for sagepay on a windows server

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt, opayo

Our company primarily used vbscript until fairly recently, when we started changing to PHP. Upon trying to integrate a SagePay form kit into one of our projects I came across this obstacle.

We are on a windows 2008 server, and this cannot be changed. The server does not contain the mcrypt library and our server host will not install it due to it being a shared platform.

The problematic line comes from a SagePay form kit that you use to pay for things with SagePay. Hopefully some of you will be familiar with these.

The line in question is:

```
//** perform encryption with PHP's MCRYPT module
$strCrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $strEncryptionPassword, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $strIV);
```

This is part of a larger encrytion function as follows:

```
//** Wrapper function do encrypt an encode based on strEncryptionType setting **
function encryptAndEncode($strIn) {

    global $strEncryptionType
          ,$strEncryptionPassword;

    if ($strEncryptionType=="XOR") 
    {
        //** XOR encryption with Base64 encoding **
        return base64Encode(simpleXor($strIn,$strEncryptionPassword));
    } 
    else 
    {
        //** AES encryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding then HEX encoding - DEFAULT **

        //** use initialization vector (IV) set from $strEncryptionPassword
        $strIV = $strEncryptionPassword;

        //** add PKCS5 padding to the text to be encypted
        $strIn = addPKCS5Padding($strIn);

        //** perform encryption with PHP's MCRYPT module
        $strCrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $strEncryptionPassword, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $strIV);

        //** perform hex encoding and return
        return "@" . bin2hex($strCrypt);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I may possibly be able to bypass this problem, or an equivalent library that I may be able to implement in its place? Any pointers, tips or points in the correct direction would be most appreciated.

**EDIT** Ok so after researching it more, as I understand it, I just need a 128 bit AES Encryption function, without the use of mcrypt.

Comment: '_Our company primarily used vbscript until fairly recently, when we started changing to PHP_' - From bad to worse, or frying pan to fire (to be more clear on the severity).

Comment: Better than standing still and getting fried.

Comment: I think they both burn pretty bad...

Comment: I sense a .net elitist... :p

Comment: Not at all, I used VB/VBA for years and even brave PHP when it's appropriate (and it's often necessary with public sector stuff). I use PHP, and my hate of it spurs from experience alone, not from my partiality toward any other language or technology. I would question my awareness of my own ignorance should I be seen to be making badly constructed judgements like '.NET good, ergo PHP bad'.

Comment: I am not sure if this is relevant .. but there is a mcrypt library in PHP which should be automatically included in your PHP..http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Comment: Its missing from our server, hence why I need an alternative. But thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of alternatives, the lack of support/willingness from your hosing provider would be the sticky point.

If you were on your own VPS/In a position to go down a new route. I'd recommend OpenSSL; http://www.openssl.org/ - Since you're on windows maybe check out http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Have you checked through `phpinfo()`to see what is available to you?

There is also PCrypt;
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1610-PHP-Symetric-encryption-of-data-using-only-PHP-code.html

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the native extension is phpseclib

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/