# AES/CBC/PKCS#5 Encryption Algorithm In PHP

Tags: php, encryption, aes, opayo

Im attempting to integrate the SagePay payment gateway into a website using the 'Form Integration' method.

Basically the form integration method works by inserting a FORM in a webpage and POSTing information to SagePay's servers whenever the Submit button for the FORM is selected. Before the information can be sent to SagePay's servers it must be encrypted using the AES/CBC/PKCS#5 algorithm, before being Base 64 encoded.

I have a basic knowledge of encryption but I have no experience of using it in PHP. Can anyone please help me formulate the AES/CBC/PKCS#5 algorithm in PHP please?

Here's my efforts so far:

```
$CRYPT = "Text Goes Here";

$blocksize = 16;//Does 16 Refer To 16 Bytes Or 16 Bits? 16 Bytes = 128 Bits.
$cryptLength = strlen($CRYPT);
$cryptLengthModuloBlocksize = $cryptLength % $blocksize;
$pad = $blocksize - $cryptLengthModuloBlocksize;
$padString = str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
$CRYPT = $CRYPT . $padString;

$encryptionPassword = 'password';
$Encrypted_CRYPT = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $encryptionPassword, $CRYPT, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

$Base64_Encrypted_CRYPT = base64_encode($Encrypted_CRYPT);

echo    "<form action = 'https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp' method = 'POST'>

            <input type = 'hidden' name = 'VPSProtocol' value = '3.00' />//
            <input type = 'hidden' name = 'TxType' value = 'PAYMENT' />
            <input type = 'hidden' name = 'Vendor' value = 'vendorName' />
            <input type = 'hidden' name = 'Crypt' value = '" . $Base64_Encrypted_CRYPT . "' />
            <input type= 'submit' value = 'Submit'>

        </form>";
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. (As soon as we have a PHP kit for v3.00 we'll display it on our website).

Hope the below helps you to.

Example:

AES encryption with Base64 encoding 
AES encryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding then HEX encoding

```
//** Wrapper function do encrypt an encode based on strEncryptionType setting **
function encryptAndEncode($strIn) {

global $strEncryptionType
      ,$strEncryptionPassword;

{
    //** AES encryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding then HEX encoding **

    //** use initialization vector (IV) set from $strEncryptionPassword
    $strIV = $strEncryptionPassword;

    //** add PKCS5 padding to the text to be encypted
    $strIn = addPKCS5Padding($strIn);

    //** perform encryption with PHP's MCRYPT module
    $strCrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $strEncryptionPassword, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $strIV);

    //** perform hex encoding and return
    return "@" . bin2hex($strCrypt);
}
}


//** Wrapper function do decode then decrypt based on header of the encrypted field **
function decodeAndDecrypt($strIn) {

global $strEncryptionPassword;

if (substr($strIn,0,1)=="@") 
{
    //** HEX decoding then AES decryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding  **

    //** use initialization vector (IV) set from $strEncryptionPassword
    $strIV = $strEncryptionPassword;

    //** remove the first char which is @ to flag this is AES encrypted
    $strIn = substr($strIn,1); 

    //** HEX decoding
    $strIn = pack('H*', $strIn);

    //** perform decryption with PHP's MCRYPT module
    return removePKCS5Padding(
        mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $strEncryptionPassword, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $strIV));
} 

}
```

Comment: Many thanks for you answer @SagePaySupport. I've tested the code above and I am now no longer receiving the 5068 encryption error. I did notice though that the above code uses HEX encoding, and not Base64 encoding as stated in the SagePay documentation.

Comment: Hi, yes HEX used above as there are various methods for different encryption algorythms that could be used. Our older PHP kits had examples of base64 (which are not available at present but will be soon via our website under Integration Documents>Download a Document). We recommend base64 however thought would help with an example you can play with.   Pleased you were able to get past the error 5068, that's great.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a working implementation of AES/CBC/PKCS#5 working with Sagepay's form integration
You will need mcrypt installed. sp_encryption is a define for the encryption key.

```
/**
* @param string $data - the key=value pairs separated with & 
* @return string
*/
protected function encode_data($data) {
    $strIn = $this->pkcs5_pad($data);
    $strCrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, sp_encryption, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, sp_encryption);
    return "@" . bin2hex($strCrypt);
}

/**
* @param string $data - crypt response from Sagepay
* @return string
*/
protected function decode_data($data) {
    if (substr($data, 0, 1) == "@") {
        $strIn = hex2bin(substr($data, 1));
        return $this->pkcs5_unpad(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, sp_encryption, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, sp_encryption));
    }
    return '';
}

protected function pkcs5_pad($text) {
$size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $pad = $size - (strlen($text) % $size);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

protected function pkcs5_unpad($text) {
    $pad = ord($text{strlen($text) - 1});
    if ($pad > strlen($text)) return false;
    if (strspn($text, $text{strlen($text) - 1}, strlen($text) - $pad) != $pad) {
        return false;
    }
    return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
}
```

On a side note make sure the VPSProtocol you use is '3.00' not 3, and not 3.0 as these won't work!

Hoep this helps and sagepay get some official PHP docs out soon.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using PKCS5 padding then HEX encoding as our older PHP kits used this.

You may want to have a look at a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360079/php-mcrypt-equivalent-for-sagepay-on-a-windows-server) to compare what you are sending. It is using an older protocol, v2.23 and XOR. If you are using our new protocol you will be using v3.00 and AES.

If you want to email feedback@sagepay.com we can discuss further. Please quote this forum post URL.

Sage Pay Support

Comment: Many thanks for your reply @sagepaysupport. I'm using version 3 of the protocol. I'm PKCS5 padding the CRYPT string before I encrypt it using AES. After I encrypt the string using AES, I then BASE 64 encode it. Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can see the working v3 example here: https://github.com/tolzhabayev/sagepayForm-php

Comment: Thanks - the SagePay site should link to this as an interim measure, great library, thanks!

Comment: Awesome piece of code, although the success.php seems to only return errors for me, or if I add the sagePay required php it returns an array with strange characters? Any advice Timur?

Comment: @AndrewDover yes sagePay should be required in the success.php file, i have changed the example. Array with strange characters is the response you recieve from sagepay. You'll probably wont need the whole array, just the payment status and payment id should be enough to mark the transaction as successfull

Comment: Thanks Timur, got it working successfully! Sagepay should really put your awesome work on their website!