# PHP Encrypting with AES_CBC_PKCS5

Tags: php, encryption

community.

I'm trying to access an API to get the login information of some users, since my application won't have a local database.

The team responsible for the database gave me the following info:

- Encryption type: AES_CBC_PKCS5;
- KEY: [their_key];
- IV: [their_iv];
- And a GET endpoint.

**They also gave me a sample username/password and their encrypted counterparts.**

I'm doing this:

```
echo openssl_encrypt($string, 'aes-128-cbc', $key, 0, $iv) . '<br>';
echo openssl_encrypt($string, 'aes-192-cbc', $key, 0, $iv) . '<br>';
echo openssl_encrypt($string, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0, $iv) . '<br>';
```

I also tried swaping `0` for `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` and `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`.

But none of my result matches theirs.

Up to this point, I haven't heard of this encryption type. What am I doing wrong here? I'm in need of some guidance.

Thanks, in advance, for your time.

Comment: This answer has a couple of samples that might be worth exploring: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20211996/231316

Comment: Without test data and/or reference code it is difficult to solve the issue. I'm not even clear what you're actually trying to achieve, encrypting the password to match a given ciphertext? Passwords are actually hashed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the PKCS5 padding. Here is a sample function and its usage:

```php
function pkcs5pad($text, $blocksize) {
  $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);

  return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

# Usage in your case
$padded_string = pkcs5pad($string, 16);
$encrypted_string = openssl_encrypt($padded_string, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_NO_PADDING, $iv);
```

Comment: `openssl_encrypt/decrypt()` applies PKCS7 padding by default (called PKCS5 on some platforms). It makes not much sense to disable the implicit padding and implement the _same_ padding explicitly.Btw, the flag for disabling padding is `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` (`OPENSSL_NO_PADDING` is used in the context of asymmetric encryption, both have different values).